# Unable to link Boost libs to vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I know this question has been asked a lot of times here. But after trying all the mentioned solutions I am still not able to Compile the Test Boost code.

I have followed the following Steps for installation :-

1. Unzip Boost into a new directory.
2. Start a 64-bit MSVC command prompt and change to the directory where Boost     was unzipped.
3. Run: bootstrap
4. Run: b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete --libdir=C:\Boost\lib\x64 architecture=x86 address-model=64 install
5. Add C:\Boost\include\boost-(version) to your include path in Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user property sheets.
6. Add C:\Boost\lib\x64 to your libs path in Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user property sheets.

Additionally, I have added the lib path in additional library directory.

I am trying to compile a standard code to test whether boost is working properly or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct Hello 
{
    Hello(){ 
        cout << "Hello constructor" << endl;
    }

    ~Hello(){
        cout << "Hello destructor" << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
};


int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    //Boost regex, compiled library
    boost::regex regex("^(Hello|Bye) Boost$");
    boost::cmatch helloMatches;
    boost::regex_search("Hello Boost", helloMatches, regex);
    cout << "The word between () is: " << helloMatches[1] << endl;

    //Boost shared pointer, header only library
    boost::shared_ptr<Hello> sharedHello(new Hello);

    return 0;
}
```

The linker error I am getting is:-

```
1>Sample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: class boost::basic_regex<char,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::w32_regex_traits<char> > > & __thiscall boost::basic_regex<char,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::w32_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const *,char const *,unsigned int)" (?do_assign@?$basic_regex@DU?$regex_traits@DV?$w32_regex_traits@D@boost@@@boost@@@boost@@AAEAAV12@PBD0I@Z) referenced in function "public: class boost::basic_regex<char,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::w32_regex_traits<char> > > & __thiscall boost::basic_regex<char,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::w32_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const *,char const *,unsigned int)" (?assign@?$basic_regex@DU?$regex_traits@DV?$w32_regex_traits@D@boost@@@boost@@@boost@@QAEAAV12@PBD0I@Z)
1>Sample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<char const *,class std::allocator<struct boost::sub_match<char const *> >,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::w32_regex_traits<char> > >::find(void)" (?find@?$perl_matcher@PBDV?$allocator@U?$sub_match@PBD@boost@@@std@@U?$regex_traits@DV?$w32_regex_traits@D@boost@@@boost@@@re_detail@boost@@QAE_NXZ) referenced in function "bool __cdecl boost::regex_search<char const *,class std::allocator<struct boost::sub_match<char const *> >,char,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::w32_regex_traits<char> > >(char const *,char const *,class boost::match_results<char const *,class std::allocator<struct boost::sub_match<char const *> > > &,class boost::basic_regex<char,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::w32_regex_traits<char> > > const &,enum boost::regex_constants::_match_flags,char const *)" (??$regex_search@PBDV?$allocator@U?$sub_match@PBD@boost@@@std@@DU?$regex_traits@DV?$w32_regex_traits@D@boost@@@boost@@@boost@@YA_NPBD0AAV?$match_results@PBDV?$allocator@U?$sub_match@PBD@boost@@@std@@@0@ABV?$basic_regex@DU?$regex_traits@DV?$w32_regex_traits@D@boost@@@boost@@@0@W4_match_flags@regex_constants@0@0@Z)
1>Sample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<char const *,class std::allocator<struct boost::sub_match<char const *> >,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::w32_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(class boost::basic_regex<char,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::w32_regex_traits<char> > > const &,enum boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)" (?construct_init@?$perl_matcher@PBDV?$allocator@U?$sub_match@PBD@boost@@@std@@U?$regex_traits@DV?$w32_regex_traits@D@boost@@@boost@@@re_detail@boost@@AAEXABV?$basic_regex@DU?$regex_traits@DV?$w32_regex_traits@D@boost@@@boost@@@3@W4_match_flags@regex_constants@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<char const *,class std::allocator<struct boost::sub_match<char const *> >,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::w32_regex_traits<char> > >::perl_matcher<char const *,class std::allocator<struct boost::sub_match<char const *> >,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::w32_regex_traits<char> > >(char const *,char const *,class boost::match_results<char const *,class std::allocator<struct boost::sub_match<char const *> > > &,class boost::basic_regex<char,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::w32_regex_traits<char> > > const &,enum boost::regex_constants::_match_flags,char const *)" (??0?$perl_matcher@PBDV?$allocator@U?$sub_match@PBD@boost@@@std@@U?$regex_traits@DV?$w32_regex_traits@D@boost@@@boost@@@re_detail@boost@@QAE@PBD0AAV?$match_results@PBDV?$allocator@U?$sub_match@PBD@boost@@@std@@@2@ABV?$basic_regex@DU?$regex_traits@DV?$w32_regex_traits@D@boost@@@boost@@@2@W4_match_flags@regex_constants@2@0@Z)
1>C:\Users\J.A.R.V.I.S\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Boost Sample\Debug\Boost Sample.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
1>
```

What am I missing here?
I am using VS2010 and windows 64bit.

Thanks

Comment: Did you tell it to link to the libraries? Adding just the library _path_ is not enough.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious How do I do that.

Comment: Add them to `Properties->Linker->Input->AdditionalDependencies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 issues which were giving the linker error:-

1. Additional linker dependencies absent at Properties->Linker->Input->AdditionalDependencies
2. Project was win32. Needed to convert it to x64 using configuration manager.